# Detecting exit/failure of child processes using IOCP - C++ - Windows

Tags: c++, windows, createprocess, iocp, waitformultipleobjects

I have a process manager. It might create thousands (on paper!) of child processes using createprocess function. Currently I'm using mufti-threading and WiatForMultipleObejct in order to detect exit or failure of any of the children. 
I was looking for some advice/guideline/pseud-code/link to detect the exit of child process using **IOCP** if it is possible at all!?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

You need to take a look at the [Job Object API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Specifically you create you process, assign it to a job and then associate the job with a completion port. See [JOBOBJECT_ASSOCIATE_COMPLETION_PORT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [SetInformationJobObject()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I found a solution for it. This is an old question! But thank you. The solution is similar to your suggestion.